# Where can I find decent descriptions for each Big5 facet?

Tags: measurement, personality

I need some decent explanations/descriptions for each of the 30 Big5 facets, like a1, a2, a3 etc etc.
I have been googling around for it, but all I have found are very short descriptions that vary too much.
There must be some kind of official, scientific definition of the facets somewhere, but where can I find it?

Comment: Are you only interested in the NEO PI Big 5 facet structure? It is worth noting that there are other many other factor-facet models of personality, some of which are also based on the Big 5.

Comment: As long as it's the Big 5 facets and the descriptions are more than 1-2 sentences per facet I am happy :)
The latter is my challenge

Answer (score 3):

This might help:
Costa, P. T., Jr., & McCrae, R. R. (1995). Domains and facets: Hierarchical personality assessment using the Revised NEO Personality Inventory. Journal of Personality Assessment, 64, 21–50.
It is available on the web at:
http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Paul_Costa3/publication/7402610_Domains_and_facets_hierarchical_personality_assessment_using_the_revised_NEO_personality_inventory/links/00b49515b9ad9348b8000000.pdf

Also, the test manual:
Costa, P. T., Jr., & McCrae, R. R. (1992). Revised NEO Personality Inventory (NEO PI-R) and NEO Five-Factor Inventory (NEO-FFI) professional manual. Odessa, FL: Psychological Assessment Resources.